# How to combine 2 arrays with comma separated in php

Tags: php, arrays

I need to join 2 array values separated by comma how to do it

here is my code

```
<?php 

$abc=array(   
    'Title' => 'mr',
    'FirstName'=> 'fname',
    'Middlename'=> 'mname',
    'LastName'=> 'lname',
    'Phoneno'=> 'phno',
    'Email'=> 'email',
);  
$a=2;//dynamic values
$b=3;//dynamic values
$c=2;//dynamic values

if ($a==1)  {                          
   $result = array();
   for ($i=0;$i<$b;$i++) {
      $result[] = $abc;
   }
}
elseif ($a==2)  {                          
   $result = array();
   for ($i=0;$i<$b;$i++) {
      $rr1[] = $abc;    
   }

   for ($i=0;$i<$c;$i++) {
      $rr2[] = $abc;    
   }

   $result=array($rr1,$rr2);
}


var_dump($result)

?>
```

The output is coming as array(array(rr1),array(rr2));

But i need output as array(rr1,rr2)
How to get the desired output

Comment: If you want combine both (or more arrays) you can use `array_merge` function.

http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-merge.php

In this example  `$a1 = [1,2,3,4]; $a2 = [4,5]; $res = array_merge($a1, $a2);` $res will have the next array [1,2,3,4,4,5].

Comment: if you need to array then `array(array(rr1),array(rr2));` why `array(rr1,rr2)`???

Comment: Clear your question....

Comment: I have added an answer that addresses what I think you are trying to do. If I have misunderstood you, please comment or **[edit]** your question to provide more details.

Comment: This question is Unclear because there is no expression of the exact desired output.  Without a [mcve], this page should be closed and removed.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code by using `array_fill`. It looks like if `$a == 1`, you want to have `$result` filled with `$b` copies of `$abc`, and if `$a ==2` you want to have it filled with `$b + $c` copies. You can do this directly without looping:

```
$result = array();

if ($a==1) {
    $result = array_fill(0, $b, $abc);
} elseif ($a==2) {
    $result = array_fill(0, $b + $c, $abc);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this `$result=array_merge($rr1,$rr2);` instead of `$result=array($rr1,$rr2);`

array_marge function marge the two array. :)

```
$abc=array(   
            'Title' => 'mr',
            'FirstName'=> 'fname',
            'Middlename'=> 'mname',
            'LastName'=> 'lname',
            'Phoneno'=> 'phno',
            'Email'=> 'email',
        );  
        $a=2;//dynamic values
        $b=3;//dynamic values
        $c=2;//dynamic values

        if ($a==1)  {                          
           $result = array();
           for ($i=0;$i<$b;$i++) {
              $result[] = $abc;
           }
        }
        elseif ($a==2)  {                          
           $result = array();
           for ($i=0;$i<$b;$i++) {
              $rr1[] = $abc;    
           }

           for ($i=0;$i<$c;$i++) {
              $rr2[] = $abc;    
           }

           //array_merge(array1)
           $result=array_merge($rr1,$rr2);
           //$result=array($rr1,$rr2);
        }
```